# The 'import' key in Zed's Learn Python the hard way Exercise 25

Tags: python, import

I'm having trouble importing my code into the python interpreter (powershell). I open python through powershell and when I type in "import ex24" simply nothing appears, this is using the code I copy and pasted from his site (Just to be sure):

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split(' ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words."""
    return sorted(words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off."""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

When he executes it he gets this:

```
>>> import ex25
>>> sentence = "All good things come to those who wait."
>>> words = ex25.break_words(sentence)
>>> words
['All', 'good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who', 'wait.']
>>> sorted_words = ex25.sort_words(words)
>>> sorted_words
['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_word(words)
All
>>> ex25.print_last_word(words)
wait.
>>> wrods
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'wrods' is not defined
>>> words
['good', 'things', 'come', 'to', 'those', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_word(sorted_words)
All
>>> ex25.print_last_word(sorted_words)
who
>>> sorted_words
['come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.']
>>> sorted_words = ex25.sort_sentence(sentence)
>>> sorted_words
['All', 'come', 'good', 'things', 'those', 'to', 'wait.', 'who']
>>> ex25.print_first_and_last(sentence)
All
wait.
>>> ex25.print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence)
All
who
```

Also, when I manually type out the code like I usually do, I get this error. I can't to seem what mistake I made:

> > > import ex25
> > >           Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >           File "", line 1, in 
> > >           File "ex25.py", line 1
> > >           SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xff' in file ex25.py on line 1, but no encoding declared;
> > >           eps/pep-0263.html for details

This is my manual copy (ex25):

```
def break_words(stuff):
    """This function will break up words for us."""
    words = stuff.split('  ')
    return words

def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words"""
    return sorted (words)

def print_first_word(words):
    """Prints the first word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(0)
    print word

def print_last_word(words):
    """Prints the last word after popping it off"""
    word = words.pop(-1)
    print word

def sort_sentence(sentence):
    """Takes in a full sentence and returns the sorted words."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    return sort_words(words)

def print_first_and_last(sentence):
    """Prints the first and last words of the sentence."""
    words = break_words(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)

def print_first_and_last_sorted(sentence):
    """Sorts the words then prints the first and last one."""
    words = sort_sentence(sentence)
    print_first_word(words)
    print_last_word(words)
```

Comment: indentation is wrong...

Comment: If you import it and nothing happens, there's nothing wrong with that. Your script doesn't actually run anything, so it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: (Follow-up to @AndyHayden) …and in Python, it matters.

Comment: Sorry my indentation is fine in my editor. This was my first time posting a question so my formatting is a bit off.

Comment: @Blender I had a feeling that was the case, but when he imports he gets this:

Comment: @Blender I edited my question to show his result, thanks

Comment: @Amon: That's not the output of his script. That's him typing in lines of code into the Python REPL.

Comment: @Blender Oh wow, aren't I an idiot, it all makes sense now. Thanks a lot, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your editor is putting a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the file start. These marks are invisible in many editors.

BOM makes no sense in UTF-8, so just **set your editor for saving in "unicode without BOM"** or equivalent (should be somewhere in `settings` or `preferences`).

> The byte order mark (BOM) is a Unicode character used to signal the endianness (byte order) of a text file or stream. It is encoded at U+FEFF byte order mark (BOM). BOM use is optional, and, if used, should appear at the start of the text stream.

In UTF-16 or UTF-32, the 16 or 32 bit units may be represented in [big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess) or [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianess) byte order, depending on the platform.

Since UTF-8 is stored in bytes and bytes are the same in every platform, signaling the endianness is useless. Why the Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8 - and worst yet, why some editors do it if not required nor recommended, is beyond my reach (dumb and dumber).